# $("select>option[text='xxx']") does not work

Tags: jquery

I need set default selected value with text, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="F">Firm</option>
    <option value="G" selected="selected">Government</option>
    <option value="I">Individual</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#sel>option[text='Firm']).prop("selected", true);
```

it does not work, below value is 0:

```
$("#sel>option[text='Firm']).length
```

If I use attribute value, it works, but I need use text here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to treat the text content of an element as if it were an attribute in CSS selector syntax.

You can write a filter to do it, however:

```
$('select option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "Firm";
}).whatever();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `text` is not a CSS attribute.

You can, however, use [jQuery's `:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("select > option:contains('xxx')")
```

Comment: Mind you, this searches for substrings -- so `$("select > option:contains('Firm')")` will match "Firm" as well as "Firm Mattress" and "Firmish", which might not be desirable. The first comment for [the jQuery docs page](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#comments) provides code for an alternate custom `:econtains` selector which matches exactly; the second comment provides a case-insensitive version.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the certain element based on its inner text:

```
$("#sel > option").filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML == "Firm";
}).prop("selected", true);
```